# WebApi POST not working from ajax call

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-post

Hi I am having trouble doing an ajax post to webAPi action method however I am getting the error:

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   ...","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller that
>   matches the request."}

below is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost/SomeService/api/ControllerName/TestPostMethod",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ userId: "testuser', loc: "test" }),
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        returnVal = msg;
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, msg) {
                        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                            if (xhr.status != 401) {
                                if (response.Message) {
                                    console.log(response.Message);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (response.Message) {
                                console.log(response.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

and below is my webApi method:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost()]
        public HttpResponseMessage TestPostMethod([FromUri]string userId, string loc)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, "success");
        }
```

This is how the routes are configured:

```
           config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
                constraints:null
            );
```

Comment: Found my answer here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473334/getting-no-action-was-found-from-webapi

Comment: You need to send data by defining model in `TestPostMethod` method.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to fix this (there may be other ways) would be to define a custom object like UserLocation -

```
public class UserLocation 
{
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string loc { get; set; }
}
```

After doing this, update the parameters for the TestPostMethod method to ([FromBody]UserLocation userLocation)

Assuming the method lives in a Controller named "ControllerName" this should now work (and you can access your two values from your object)

Comment: I see you answered your own question after I posted, either way - the above should work :)